# Separar dos textos con REGEX en Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Tengo un texto:

```
Hola amigos.En esta ocación quiero invitarlos a compartir de este fin de semana.Atm. Carlos Cadi.Ángeles
```

Quisiera que se separe entre espacios despues del punto, solo cuando la primera letra empiece con Mayusculas. Es decir el texto resultante quedaria así:

```
Hola amigos. En esta ocación quiero invitarlos a compartir de este fin de semana. Atm. Carlos Cadi. Ángeles
```

Hice mi avance de esta forma en python

```
import re
text = 'Hola amigos.En esta ocación quiero invitarlos a compartir de este fin de semana.Atm. Carlos Cadi.Ángeles'
text_regex = re.split("\.([A-Z]{1}[a-záéíóúñ]+)", text)
result_text = '. '.join(text_regex)
print('Text regex:', text_result)
```

El resultado actual me arroja asi:

```
Hola amigos. En.  esta ocación quiero invitarlos a compartir de este fin de semana. Atm. . Carlos Cadi.Ángeles
```

*Detalles a pulir*:

- Despues de **En.**, no debe haber un espacio en blanco por demás
- Despues de **Atm.**, no debe haber un espacio ni punto
- **Cadi.Ángeles**, debe separar incluso cuando la primera letra lleva tilde y es mayúscula

¿Cómo lo puedo reajustar para que obtener la salida correcta?.
Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución:

```
patron = re.compile(r"\.([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ])")
text_regex = patron.sub(r". \1", text)
```

La expresión regular detecta simplemente un punto seguido de una mayúscula. Sólo he puestos algunas mayúsculas con acentos, para demostrar como se hace.

Con el patrón compilado procedemos ha buscar y reemplazar con ". \1". El "\1" en este contexto se refiere al primer grupo de captura dentro de la expresión regular, es decir, nos da la letra mayúscula después del punto.

#### Demo

```
import re
text = 'Hola amigos.En esta ocasión quiero invitarlos a compartir de este fin de semana.Atm. Carlos Cadi.Ángeles'
patron = re.compile(r"\.([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ])")
text_regex = patron.sub(r". \1", text)
print('Text regex:', text_regex)
```

produce:

```
Text regex: Hola amigos. En esta ocasión quiero invitarlos a compartir de este fin de semana. Atm. Carlos Cadi. Ángeles

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias Candid, es una solución perfecta.